# Aborto del programa al eliminar array de doble puntero en función recursiva a nivel 3

Tags: c++, punteros, manejo-de-memoria, array-bidimensional

¡Hola!

Quería hacer un programa simple para calcular la determinante de una matriz construida con doble puntero, sin embargo estoy teniendo un problema al liberar el espacio de memoria en la función cuando el nivel de recursividad llega a tres:

```
float det(float **A, size_t n)
{
    //Casos especiales
    if (n < 1) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return A[0][0];
    if (n == 2) return A[0][0]*A[1][1]-A[0][1]*A[1][0];
        
    //Calcular por cofactores
    float sum = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        //Crear el menor
        float **menor = new float *[n - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            menor[i] = new float[n - 1];
            
        //Excluir la columna 0 y la fila c de A en el menor
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                menor[i][j] = i < c ? A[i][j + 1] : A[i + 1][j + 1];
            
        //Fórmula del cofactor
        sum += pow(-1, c) * A[c][0] * det(menor, n - 1);
        
        //borrar el menor
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            delete[] menor[i];
        delete[] menor;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

He probado el algoritmo sin eliminar los punteros y funciona, da la determinante esperada, pero si pongo el bloque de código "borrar el menor", el programa deja de funcionar, tras un poco de depuración vi que sucede para matrices de más de 3 filas y columnas y no entiendo muy bien por qué sucede. No tiene problema para borrar los menores de 2x2, pero al terminar el primer cofactor de una matriz de 4x4 y disponerse a borrar el menor de 3x3 el programa aborta con este error:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000a26d40 ***
det(A) = Aborted (core dumped)
```

De lo poco que he entendido en la depuración, cuando llega al punto de borrar el primer menor de 3x3 dice que intentó borrar una dirección que no existía, y no entiendo por qué está sucediendo eso... Espero que puedan ayudarme a entender lo que está pasando.

Comment: En el for despues de "// Crear el menor" pones de condición `i < n` cuando debería ser `i < n - 1`. Con esa corrección te sigue mostrando el error?

Comment: ¡Sí! ¡Era eso! Como el error se producía al momento de eliminar di por sentado que lo demás estaba bien. Gracias, ahora funciona perfecto.